# How can i get tweets on my website?

Tags: jquery, twitter

I am trying with this code but there is an error like '{"lookup":"error","response":"unknown error"}'

```
$('.twitter_feed').getmytweets({
    twitter_sn: 'username', /* my twitter username */
    twitter_wrap: 'tweet', /* wrap each tweet with a class */
    twitter_limit: 1, /* how many tweets to return */
    twitter_pp: false, /* display your profile picture */
    twitter_stats: false, /* display your twitter stats */
    twitter_details: false /* display your details (name, location) */
});
```

Comment: Doesn't look much like php to me. Are you sure this isn't javascript?

Comment: What library are you using to retrieve the tweets? What does getmytweets do?

Comment: open your favorite client debugger (F12), you should see the requests going in the "Network" tab, you'll have more luck debugging from there.

Comment: Library is min.tweet.3.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a fiddle, please check [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/48qwY/) and its working.

It is really slow. You may want to try in PHP.